# Alternatives to Deprecated Google News API

Tags: json, api, deprecated, google-news

What are some alternatives to the comprehensive and now deprecated Google News API?

I'm trying to load some JSON data from two government webservices to be parsed into a query for a news API which will send me back hefty relevant news.

It will be over economic and regional data. So it could be lowest paying job in dallas county.

Are there any news api with as much functionality?

Comment: Answer to the similar question about third-party Google News API: stackoverflow.com/a/61015947/1291371

Answer (score 2):

This is a relatively old question, but there have been lots of recent developments in the News API space and I thought I could shed some light.

I’m going to immediately disregard the more expensive choices like Bing ($7/1,000 requests), since most people won’t find it easy to afford them, and the results are actually often inferior to more specialized solutions.

That means you’re basically left with two options: [News API](https://contextualweb.io/news-api/) and [newsapi.org](https://newsapi.org/). I really do enjoy newsapi.org, they do a fantastic job and provide high quality search results. They also provide developers with 500 free requests per day, which is pretty great.

ContextualWeb News API does have a couple of advantages: they offer 10,000 requests per month free, and after that our API is significantly cheaper and more flexible (the baseline is $0.5/1000 requests, compared with a slightly higher $1.8/1000 requests with newsapi.org’s basic plan). ContextualWeb also offers result keywords, allowing you to do all kinds of nifty machine learning stuff with the search results.

Having said that, newsapi.org’s documentation is currently more straightforward, and their results are mostly always spot on.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the  [Social Animal NEWS API](https://api.socialanimal.com/).

The news database has 450 million-plus articles and 1 million articles are added on a daily basis.

**Notable features:**

- It is fast and provides breaking news across the web in 39 languages.
- Social engagement data is available for all news URLs which enables surfacing top quality articles
- Offers Sentiment Analysis to filter articles based on their sentiments.

For more details, please visit the [documentation page](https://api.socialanimal.com/api/doc/).

Disclaimer: I work for Social Animal.

Answer (score 0):

There's a free alternative that provides good data but the quantity of query is limited.

If you want to get a higher number of query per day you must pay a subscription.

The site is called [gnews.io](https://gnews.io), it's really simple to authenticate and to get a key.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a general news api site like newsapi.org or if you want more specific niche news (e.g. stocks) you can search for niche api's like iex, alphavantage or [stocknewsapi.com](https://stocknewsapi.com)

Answer (score 0):

Aylien provides a News API that gives you access to NLP-enriched news articles from 80,000+ news sources: https://aylien.com/product/news-api/demo

Answer (score -1):

The Newsdata.io API is a simple news API with this you can search over 50,000 news data sources worldwide. You can use this API to get live-breaking news from any country in the world in your preferred language as they provide news data in 22 languages in 7 categories from 88 countries.

Newsdata.io allows you to search for published articles using keywords or phrases, languages, publications, time. You can sort the results by time, the popularity of the publication source, or location.

Newsdata.io also provides news data analysis and it includes data analysis like topic labeling, intent detection, sentiment analysis, emotion analysis, entity extraction, semantic similarities.

The Newsdata.io API is free to use for non-commercial purposes with 500 API requests per day with 10 articles per request, 99.99% SLA uptime.

Data format: The API sends quick GET HTTP requests and returns JSON results.
Ease of use: The API is simple to use. Furthermore, you can use its documentation to get started implementing the API in a matter of minutes.

Comment: Hi Rajat, not sure why this got downvoted, but could be because it reads like an ad.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you could try [Google BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing)